# Putting HTML in ASPX - possible?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a aspx page that begins like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main_MP_Teacher.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Teacher_default" Title="Teacher Page" %>
```

I want to include html in this page also but when I put in the first line

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/strict.dtd">
```

I get a parse error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?Can you explain?

Comment: As you can see it uses a MasterPageFile "~/Main_MP_Teacher.master, this is a menu bar with links. One of these is a logout button. I need to create 30 pages where the user can upload files to a specific folder and the form to do this is in HTML. I want to add the form to this page

Answer (score 7):

The parser error is probably because you're putting something other than `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` in the root of your ASPX page.

If you're using a `MasterPageFile` then the `<!DOCTYPE` should be at the start of the MasterPage.

This is unless you have a `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` right at the start of the MasterPage, which you can put the `<!DOCTYPE` into it.

**MORE INFORMATION**

The `<!DOCTYPE` should always be the very first thing in the HTML file, so normally your MasterPage would look something like this...

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeBehind="MyMaster.master.vb" Inherits="dev.MyMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="myHeader"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="myBody"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If for some reason you wanted to have a page specified doc type, then you could add a new placeholder at the start, with a default value...

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeBehind="MyMaster.master.vb" Inherits="dev.MyMaster" %>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="myDocType">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/strict.dtd">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<html>
  ...
</html>
```

And then in the page you want to override put the following (by NOT overriding, the original will be output instead)...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="MyMaster.master" Codebehind="MyPage.aspx.vb"
  Inherits="dev.MyPage" Title="My Page" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderId="myDocType">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
</asp:Content>
...
```